# Making a boxplot based on continuous values

Tags: r, dataframe

Using 2 classifications, I want to create a boxplot to illustrate the variation in starting and ending times.  How I could do this with ggplot?

Data structure:

[image]

Desired output:

[image: Desired output:]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(day = c("Mo", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Mo", 
"Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri"), start_time1 = c(9.75, 6.5, 6.5, 
6.5, 6.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.75), end_time1 = c(14.75, 14.75, 
8.75, 8.75, 14.75, 17.75, 17.25, 17.25, 16.5, 17.5), Pattern = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(day = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), start_time1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), end_time1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Pattern = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Both your scales are discrete, I cannot understand, how do you want to plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not very clear what you want to do, so I'm trying to guess:
Personally, I would put the `day` on the x-axis, the times on the y-axis, using the colors to differentiate `Patterns` and facet to differentiate the starting or ending times

```
library(ggplot2)

m <- melt(dff,id.vars=c("day","Pattern"))
m$Pattern <- as.factor(m$Pattern)
ggplot(m,aes(x=day,y=value,fill=Pattern))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~variable)+
  labs(y="times")
```

the output depends on the length and variability of the data. With the sample that you provided the output is not so informative. Trying to inject some randomness in the data the plot becomes more useful:

[image]